# Blank Page at the end in XML/BI Publisher

Tags: ms-word, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

In some templates, I am getting a blank page at the end of the RTF output for a XML/BI Publisher template(defined as rtf). Is there any way of avoiding it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have unnecessary new lines and spaces in your template. One way to see this is by enabling the Hide/Show button in MS word.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0